# Identity can't connect to remote DB, keep connecting to local DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, database-connection, connection-string, identity

I'm working with `Identity` framework and ASP.NET MVC5 (DB First).
Everything is OK locally, but Identity can't connect to my remote DB hosted on Azure.

My connection strings in `web.config` looks like this

```
<!-- Local DB -->
<add name="MyEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyLocalDBName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<!-- Remote DB -->
<add name="MyEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:MyServerName.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=MyRemoteDBName;persist security info=False;user id=MyID;password=MyPassword;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;application name=EntityFramework;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  />
```

(When i want to debug with remote datas, the local DB is obviously commented, and vice versa)

The weird thing is Identity is always going to the **LOCAL** DB (it even creates a new DB called `MyRemoteDBName` but locally the first time I launch my app).
However, Entity Framework is correctly going to the remote DB and display datas from remote DB !

I also have this class in my `IdentityModels.cs` :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyLocalDBName", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I guess I'm wrong here : `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyLocalDBName", throwIfV1Schema: false)` ?

I tried to replace `MyLocalDBName` by `MyRemoteDBName`, but `MyRemoteDBName` is created locally (?!)

Why is Identity always going to the *local* DB whereas Entity Framework is correctly going to the *remote* DB ?

**EDIT** :

Here is how I instanciate my `ApplicationDbContext` :

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
```

Comment: Does your `web.config` has any more connection string named `MyLocalDBName`. cause we normally pass connection string name in base constructor in this code `public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyLocalDBName", throwIfV1Schema: false)`.

Comment: Nop, my `web.config` only has the 2 connection strings I wrote in my initial question. SHould I change something in `App.config` or somewhere else ?

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET Entity Framework DB first?, cause the connection string you wrote in your question, is appears like it?

Comment: Please try to change `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyLocalDBName", throwIfV1Schema: false)` to  `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)`.

Comment: I tried to use `base("MyEntities", ...)`, and it raises an exception the first time I use Identity : 
`The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context`.
I'm googling this error. And yes Im' using EF DB first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string you are using, is for EF ADO.NET Model. It can't be understand by Identity. So you need to add one more connection string for Identity, as:

```
<!-- Local DB -->
<add name="IdentityConnection" connectionString="data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyLocalDBName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<!-- Remote DB -->
<add name="IdentityConnection" 
     connectionString="data source=tcp:MyServerName.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=MyRemoteDBName;persist security info=False;user id=MyID;password=MyPassword;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

and use it on `ApplicationDbContext` as:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("IdentityConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need further investigation before accepting your answer (i'm going to do it this afternoon) but it seems it's working, thank you so much !! However, can you explain me how on earth it was possible it worked before ?? I had only one connection string since I started on this project and it worked well (locally).

Comment: It was working because, `DbContext` constructor accepts `Database` Name or `ConnectionString` Name as parameter. If you are passing `Database` Name in `DbContext` Constructor it will look into your local Database Server for the database. So, in case of remote connection you need to specify a separate `Connection String` for it.

Comment: Ok I see... Thank you very much for the explaination and the solution :-)